# Latex: Add Image Above the Title

Tags: pdftex, titles

I have an Image, and I would like to add the image above the Title. The Downbelow Code gives the entire page to the Image. I want the image and the Title, Autother to be displayed on the same page

```
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{images/Company_Groups.jpg}~\\[1cm]
\title{xxxxxxx
\\In xxxxx }
\author{N. N. Arif
\\ xxxx in headquarters, xxxxx}
\date{June 18, 2015}
\maketitle
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't recommend that `\\[...]` stuff there, but it's possible to include the graphic file as part of the title itself.

(Remove the `demo` option afterwards)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\title{%
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{images/Company_Groups.jpg}~ 
\\[1cm]
xxxxxxx
\\In xxxxx 
}
\author{N. N. Arif
\\ xxxx in headquarters, xxxxx}
\date{June 18, 2015}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some update, with the famous [CTAN TeX Lion](http://www.ctan.org/lion) (copyright by Duane Bibby)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\title{%
%\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{images/Company_Groups.jpg}~ 
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{ctanlion}~\\[1cm]
xxxxxxx\\
In xxxxx 
}
\author{N. N. Arif
\\ xxxx in headquarters, xxxxx}
\date{June 18, 2015}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. The structure became good, but the image appear as Black Square.

Comment: Why Would u not recommend to include the Graphical file part of the title?

Comment: I removed the DEMO, But I got different errors and the image is moved to right side. 
The errors that I got was: There is not line here to end, Cannot determine size of the image...

Comment: @Arif: I meant the `\\[...]` spacing stuff, not the graphics

Comment: @Arif: It works for me, without `demo` too, when using a specific graphics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, but there is some strange issue. As soon I add Images than it doesnt display them in the center, it ads them more to the RIGHT. USING DEMO shows the structure I want.

Comment: @Arif: Do you use another `documentclass`?